# Plastic deformation energy dissipation due to inelastic collision

Tags: collision, elasticity, stress-strain, solid-mechanics

I have been attempting to determine an analytical expression for the coefficient of restitution (or any similar collision parameter) for an inelastic collision. So far, I've looked at Hertzian contact mechanics to describe the pressures (which can be determined from initial body velocities) and deformations for an elastic collision. From this, I have identified the applied pressure due to the contact of two colliding bodies required to cause the first onset of yield, giving the maximum contact pressure for a collision to be elastic. However, I am curious about what happens beyond first yield.

In particular, I want to determine energy dissipation due to plastic deformation for pressures beyond first yield, so that I can determine the loss of kinetic energy in a collision. My understanding is that, as you increase the pressure beyond first yield, a plastic zone develops and extends from a point that lies underneath the surface of contact in each body, but I don't believe I know how to determine energy dissipation from this.

I have also looked at the elastic analysis of a point load per unit width on a semi-infinite plane using Airy stress functions (which could be extended to Hertzian pressure distributions by integration), but I am not sure how to extend this solution to 3D, or how to consider plastic effects.

Does there exist any experimental data or theory to suggest a relationship between plastic energy dissipation and Hertzian contact pressure?

Comment: Maybe this will interest you: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230925942_Viscoelastic_Modelling_of_Tennis_Ball_Properties as you will see behind the inelastic behavior of shocks there are often viscoelastic models rather than plastic models.